# Error después de eliminar un li jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Buenas

Tengo un problema que no se de donde viene. 
Tengo una lista de este modo:

```
    <ul>
      <li id="linea_1"><div onclick="accion();"></div></li>
      <li id="linea_2"><div onclick="accion();"></div></li>
      .
      .
      .
     </ul>
```

Añado y elimino `<li>` mediante jquery, para añadir no tengo ningún problema, pero al eliminar una linea de este modo `$("#linea_"+id).remove()` la linea se elimina correctamente pero las lineas sucesivas dejan de estar habilitadas.
Es decir, si elimino la linea 3, las lineas 4,5,6... no se pueden seleccionar, se ven en la lista pero no se pueden seleccionar.

Comment: ¿Qué significa que no se pueden seleccionar? Son elementos de una lista, son elementos visibles y no se seleccionan. ¿Podrías explicar tu problema con una visión más amplia de lo que estás usando? ¿Usas bootstrap? ¿Alguna función para crear menús o similar?

Comment: que no se pueden seleccionar es que no se detecta el evento click.  La lista esta creada en html y la creo en un primer momento vacia, despues utilizo una funcion en javascript para añadir/eliminar las lineas y modificar la opcion class, pero todo esto lo hago desde el evento click definido en el div de la linea.

Comment: No consigo reproducir tu problema. A mí tal y como lo tienes me funciona correctamente. Si no nos pones en un contexto mayor o nos das una URL para probar lo que te pasa a todo el mundo le va a funcionar el código sin saber cuál es el problema que estás teniendo realmente.

Answer (score 2):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo funcionando. Después de eliminar uno, el resto siguen funcionando.

```js
function eliminar(id) {
  $("#linea_"+id).remove();
}

function accion(id) {
  console.log("HOLA");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div onclick="eliminar(1)">Eliminar A</div>
</td><td>
<div onclick="eliminar(2)">Eliminar B</div>
</td><td>
<div onclick="eliminar(3)">Eliminar C</div>
</td><td>
<div onclick="eliminar(4)">Eliminar D</div>
</td><td>
<div onclick="eliminar(5)">Eliminar E</div>
</td><td>
<div onclick="eliminar(6)">Eliminar F</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<ul>
      <li id="linea_1"><div onclick="accion();">A</div></li>
      <li id="linea_2"><div onclick="accion();">B</div></li>
      <li id="linea_3"><div onclick="accion();">C</div></li>
      <li id="linea_4"><div onclick="accion();">D</div></li>
      <li id="linea_5"><div onclick="accion();">E</div></li>
      <li id="linea_6"><div onclick="accion();">F</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Un ejemplo simple en `Vainilla JS`:

```js
function accion(item){        
       
   let id = item.parentElement.id;
    
   console.log(id);
    
   document.getElementById(id).outerHTML= '';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="linea_1"><div onclick="accion(this);">li 1</div></li>
  <li id="linea_2"><div onclick="accion(this);">li 2</div></li>
  <li id="linea_3"><div onclick="accion(this);">li 3</div></li>
  <li id="linea_4"><div onclick="accion(this);">li 4</div></li>
  <li id="linea_5"><div onclick="accion(this);">li 5</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que tras generar un elemento de forma dinámica, como no existe en el código original, jQuery no puede encontrar el elemento "li" con ese id.

En vez de llamar al evento click() del "li", usa lo siguiente:

```
$(document).on("click","#id_del_li",function(){
  //lo que quieras hacer con el li
});
```